# JIRA Rest API over python

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on a python project in which one of the steps involves releasing the code of a specific team called "X".

Now I'm trying to automate this process. I'm new to REST API development, but  after googling, I've got the gist of what REST API is all about.

I am thinking to query the JIRA server with the request for a keyword "X" and get the resultant metadata.

I can parse through the metadata to determine SVN url and then release the code.

Now my question is can this be achieved using REST API, if so can anybody provide me a demo example?

Comment: Have you checked out https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform as of yet?

Comment: HI Robert, i checked out the link you mentioned ; but it contains examples involving a user assigned to an issue and not keyword search in the request .

Comment: check out these project samples - https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e3723 They should get you started with the kind of URL to request

Comment: Thanks a TON , that was very helpful , also will it be possible for you to send me a link which explains how to setup the development ecosystem in order to access JIRA through rest via a python script ; i mean do we need any other python frameworks to achieve that ?

Comment: That's a different question, and really not one suited to this site.  You're better off trying some things on your own first, and then return here with specific technical questions ("I wrote this code, and I expect it to to this thing, but instead I get this error....").

Comment: @user106351 glad that helped - as larsks mentioned, please try a few things and post any problems you have as a separate question and the community will be glad to help.